# Api routes not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to call an api route from postman like this

`http://project.app/api/someroute`

But it does not work and through that error

`file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/project/storage/framework/cache/data/a0/c6/a0c65d98bc6f1fe2c35f8ba5fd47c8a3e225165e): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this directory manually:

```
/storage/framework/cache
```

Also, make sure you have:

```
/storage/framework/views
/storage/framework/sessions
```

Usually, you'll also need to set the right permissions on the `storage` directory:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

Comment: i already have all these directories and also have the permission set to -R 777 but it still does not work.

Comment: @kuldeepsingh you have the directory and you still get exactly the same error which says you don't have this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check

1) Make sure you add an api_token column to your users database.

`$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique()`

2) Add a random 60 character string to that column

3) Add a route to your api.php routes file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function ()
{
    Route::get('test', function(){
        return ['name' => 'zechdc'];
    });
});
```

Notice I added a prefix of v1. Looks like laravel already adds an 'api' prefix as well.

4) Visit your url and append your api_token you created for a user. You should see some JSON on your screen at this point.

`http://localhost/api/v1/test?api_token=wwfaadmcmsvbtldzxlenjxhxakwyriwhrxcbkgfpnlccyhhxexvzfixxjtjq`

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/53-api-routes-auth-middleware-confusion?page=1

Comment: **Notice I added a prefix of v1. Looks like laravel already adds an 'api' prefix as well.**
   |   
run `php artisan route:list` for proof